# GitLab Running - Unable to trust self signed certificate

Tags: git, ssl, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

When running GitLab CI Runner I have to specify

> environment = ["GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true"]"

Without it I get the following error from GitLab CI

```
Cloning into 'D:/GitRunner/builds/c2RN8y5j/0/joeybob/mytestproect'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@myserver.local/joeybob/mytestproect.git/': error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: D:\GitRunner\builds\c2RN8y5j\0\joeybob\mytestproect.tmp\CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE
  CApath: none
```

Checking the contents of CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE I can see that it matches the expected values between BEGIN CERTIFICATE and END CERTIFICATE.

When I incude GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true the CI window produces the following error but still succeeds

```
WARNING: Failed to load system CertPool: crypto/x509: system root pool is not available on Windows 
ERROR: Failed to parse PEM in D:\GitRunner\builds\c2RN8y5j\0\joeybob\mytestproect.tmp\CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE
```

I assume there is something wrong with the PEM (crt) file. I'm running this on Windows Server 2016 and I exported the certificate from my local trusted root certificate store in the base-64 encoded X.509 format. Could this issue be to do with the way windows encodes the file?

Comment: I realized that the pem file in the builds folder is being copied there with mixed line endings..... That also happens when I save the pem file with windows endings. I dont't know yet how to prevent that

Comment: @Micromegas sorry no I had to blindly trust the certificate in the end which is not what is safe nor what I wanted to do :(

Answer (score 0):

Joey, this probably might be too late and of no use for you anymore, yet maybe it will also help you. I had the exact same issue and solved it the following way:

**This is what I assume you've already done:**

1. Register the runner passing it the certificate with the argument `gitlab-runner register --tls-ca-file=/path` (certificate must be in .pem format)
2. Set `environment = ["GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true"]"`.
3. Import the certificate as a trusted root certificate in windows.

Now here comes the kicker:

**3. Copy the content of the certificate multiple times into the .pem file**

With that I mean, you just open the .pem file copy the content and paste it multiple times into the same file. Save it and let the pipeline run again. You should not see any errors anymore.

The problem is that the contents are at fault. The problem is that the UTF-8 is BOMed since the contents are converted from byte to string.

Adding the certs multiple times in the file should get rid of the error in your Runner. This is much more a workaround than a solution but quickly done and at least sth.

For more on this: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/4814

and: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2173#note_24022134

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

`CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE` is actually a workaround by gitlab (self signed certificate for `gitlab.com`), you can remove it, because your internal machine (docker container) CA can handle `gitlab.com` without workarounds.

```
http.https://gitlab.com.sslcainfo=/home/gitlab-runner/builds/EBo-xXLj/0/user/project.tmp/CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

# It will remove CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE.
git config --unset http.https://gitlab.com.sslCAInfo || :

# I can fetch something
git fetch

# I can commit and push something
git add . && git commit -m "update" && git push
```